# Remove special character from a column in dataframe

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, character-encoding, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to remove a special character (**å**) from a column in a dataframe.

My data looks like:

```
ClientID,PatientID 
AR0001å,DH_HL704221157198295_91
AR00022,DH_HL704221157198295_92
```

My original data is approx 8TB in size from which I need to get rid of this special character.

Code to load data:

```
reader.option("header", true)
  .option("sep", ",")
  .option("inferSchema", false)
  .option("charset", "ISO-8859-1")
  .schema(schema)
  .csv(path)
```

After loading into dataframe when I do `df.show()` it shows:

```
+--------+--------------------+
|ClientID|           PatientID|
+--------+--------------------+
|AR0001Ã¥|DH_HL704221157198...|
|AR00022 |DH_HL704221157198...|
+--------+--------------------+
```

Code I used to try to replace this character:

```
df.withColumn("ClientID", functions.regexp_replace(df.col("ClientID"), "\å", ""));
```

But this didn't work. While loading the data in dataframe if I change the charset to "UTF-8" it works.

I am not able to find a solution with the current charset (ISO-8859-1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some things to note,

- Make sure to assign the result to a new variable and use that afterwards
- You do not need to escape "å" with `\`
- `colName` in the command should be `ClientId` or `PatientID`

If you did all these things, then I would suggest to, instead of matching on "å", try matching on the characters you want to keep. For example, for the `ClientID` column,

```
df.withColumn("ClientID", functions.regexp_replace(df.col("ClientID"), "[^A-Z0-9_]", ""));
```

---

Another approach would be to convert the UTF-8 character "å" to it's ISO-8859-1 equivalent and replace with the resulting string.

```
String escapeChar = new String("å".getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't remove all special characters from the data. There are few columns in the data where some of these special characters like ® have meaning. I don't have a subsets which tells what to keep and what to remove. The requirement comes in as to remove a given special character from a particular column.

Comment: @abhiadh `regexp_replace(df.col("ClientID"), "Ã¥", "")` seems to work for me when using ISO-8859-1 (with scala).

Comment: Yes that worked indeed. I converted the special character "å" before passing to the function and it worked.
`new String("å".getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");`
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The below command will remove all the special characters and will keep all the lower/upper case alphabets and all the numbers in the string:

```
df.withColumn("ClientID", functions.regexp_replace(df.col("ClientID"), "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ""));
```